# Python "==" returning False when it should return True

Tags: python, sockets

I've been experimenting recently with password protecting sockets in python and I've come across an issue.

When checking the clients input with the servers set password the server seems to think the set password isn't the same as the password input by the user.

My first script: server.py

```
import socket
import threading
from requests import get
import uuid
HEADER = 64
PORT = 9090
#To connect over the internet change SERVER to your public IP
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr, password):
    print(f"[PNet] NEW CONNECTION: {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            print(msg)
            if msg == password:
                connected = True
            if msg != password:
                print("Huh?")
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
            print(f"[PNet] {addr}: {msg}")
            conn.send("[PNet] CLIENT: Message received.".encode(FORMAT))
    conn.close()
    
def start():
    print("[PNet] STARTING: Server is starting...")
    print("[PNet] STARTING: Generating key...")
    password = uuid.uuid4()
    print(f"[PNet] FINALIZING: Key generated: {password}")
    server.listen()
    print(f"[PNet] LISTENING: Server is listening on {SERVER}.")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr, password))
        thread.start()
        #print(f"[PNet] ACTIVE CONNECTIONS: {threading.activeCount() - 1}")
        
start()
```

and my second script: client.py

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 9090
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = input("[PNet] CLIENT: Server IP: ")
PASS = input("[PNet] SERVER: Enter password: ")
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

send(PASS)

connected = True
while connected:
    msg = input("[PNet] CLIENT: Send a message: ")
    if msg != DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        send(msg)
    else:
        send(msg)
        connected = False
```

when run, and the password is copied exactly from the terminal it still returns False. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please be aware that `socket.recv(n)` is **not guaranteed** to return `n` bytes.  You might need to iteratively read until you’ve got enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comapring UUID object with a string, thats why its returning false,

to check, put a print before comparing,

```
...
print(type(msg),type(password)) # will print <class 'str'> <class 'uuid.UUID'>

if msg == password:
    connected = True
...
```

to solve it pass the password as string,

```
password = str(uuid.uuid4())
```